# Unable to login(android application)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I am to create a registration page and a login page.After  Registering when i am trying to login,its showing password mismatch,,I am unable to find any error..Please help

LoginActivity1.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

    Button mLogin;
    Button mRegister;

    EditText muname;
    EditText mpassword;

    DBHelper2 DB2 = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Registration2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.login:

                muname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ledituname);
                mpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Leditpw);

                String username = muname.getText().toString();
                String password = mpassword.getText().toString();

                if (username.equals("") || username == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter User Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (password.equals("") || password == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    boolean validLogin = validateLogin(username, password,
                            getBaseContext());
                    if (validLogin) {
                        // System.out.println("In Valid");
                        //Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TabBar.class);
                        // in.putExtra("UserName", muname.getText().toString());
                        //startActivity(in);
                        Intent i1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TabBar.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Success Valid Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        startActivity(i1);
                        // finish();
                    }
                   /* else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Register First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }*/
                }
                break;

            }

        }

        private boolean validateLogin(String username, String password,
                Context baseContext) {
            DB2 = new DBHelper2(getBaseContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db2 = DB2.getReadableDatabase();

            String[] columns = { "id" };

            String selection = "username=? AND password=?";
            String[] selectionArgs = { username, password };

            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {

                cursor = db2.query(DBHelper2.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, columns, selection,
                        selectionArgs, null, null, null);
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
            } catch (Exception e)

            {
               System.out.println("Excetion in valid login"+e.getMessage());
            }
            int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

            if (numberOfRows <= 0) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User Name and Password miss match.Register First.\nPlease Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }

            return true;

        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            DB2.close();
        }
    }
```

Registartion2.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.os.Build;

public class Registration2 extends Activity  implements OnClickListener,
OnItemSelectedListener
{

    private Button mSubmit;
    private Button mCancel;
    private EditText mGname;
    private EditText mFname;
    private EditText mMname;
    private EditText mAddress1;
    private EditText mAddress2;
    private EditText mCityvillage;
    private EditText mStateprovince;
    private EditText mCountry;
    private EditText mPostalcode;
    private EditText mAge;
    private EditText mBirthdate;
    private Spinner mGender;
    private EditText mUsername;
    private EditText mpass;

    private String Gen;

    protected DBHelper2 DB2 = new DBHelper2(Registration2.this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration1);


        // Assignment of UI fields to the variables
                mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
                mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

                mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                mCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

                mGname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.egname);
                mFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.efname);
                mMname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMname);
                mAddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eaddress1);
                mAddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eaddress2);
                mCityvillage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ecityvillage);
                mStateprovince = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.estateprovince);
                mCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ecountry);
                mPostalcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.epostalcode);
                mAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eage);
                mBirthdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ebirthdate);
                mGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eusername);
                mpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.epass);


                // Spinner method to read the on selected value
                ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] {
                                new State("Male"), new State("Female") });
                mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.cancel:
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // finish();
            break;

        case R.id.submit:
            String gname = mGname.getText().toString();
            String fname = mFname.getText().toString();
            String mname = mMname.getText().toString();
            String address1 = mAddress1.getText().toString();

            String address2 = mAddress2.getText().toString();
            String cityvillage = mCityvillage.getText().toString();
            String stateprovince = mStateprovince.getText().toString();
            String country = mCountry.getText().toString();

            String postalcode = mPostalcode.getText().toString();
            String age = mAge.getText().toString();
            String birthdate = mBirthdate.getText().toString();
            Gen = mGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = mpass.getText().toString();

            boolean invalid = false;

            if (gname.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your Givenname",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else

            if (fname.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your firstname", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else

            if (mname.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your middlename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else

            if (address1.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your address1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else if (address2.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your address2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else if (cityvillage.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your cityvillage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (stateprovince.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your stateprovince", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (country.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your country", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (postalcode.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your postalcode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (age.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your age", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (birthdate.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your birthdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (username.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (password.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            else if (invalid == false) 
            {
                addEntry(gname, fname, mname, address1, address2, cityvillage,
                        stateprovince, country, postalcode, age, birthdate, Gen,
                        username,password);
                Intent i_register = new Intent(Registration2.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i_register);
                // finish();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        DB2.close();
    }

    private void addEntry(String gname,String fname,String mname,String address1,String address2,String cityvillage,String
            stateprovince,String country,String postalcode,String age,String birthdate,String Gen,String username,String password) 
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db2 = DB2.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put("id", 2);
        values.put("givenname", gname);
        values.put("firstname", fname);
        values.put("middlename", mname);
        values.put("address1", address1);
        values.put("address2", address2);
        values.put("cityvillage", cityvillage);
        values.put("stateprovince", stateprovince);
        values.put("country", country);
        values.put("postalcode", postalcode);
        values.put("age", age);
        values.put("birthdate", birthdate);
        values.put("gender", Gen);
        values.put("username", username);
        values.put("password", password);

        try {
            long rowId = db2.insert(DBHelper2.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            System.out.println("rowId: "+rowId);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "your details submitted Successfully...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
        State st = (State) mGender.getSelectedItem();

        // Show it via a toast
        toastState("onItemSelected", st);
    }

    public void toastState(String name, State st) {
        if (st != null) {
            Gen = st.name;
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Gen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

DBHelper2.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    private SQLiteDatabase db2;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_GNAME = "givenname";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME = "firstname";
    public static final String KEY_MNAME = "middlename";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS1 = "address1";

    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS2 = "address2";
    public static final String KEY_CITYVILLAGE = "cityvillage";
    public static final String KEY_STATEPROVINCE = "stateprovince";
    public static final String KEY_COUNTRY= "country";

    public static final String KEY_POSTALCODE= "postalcode";
    public static final String KEY_AGE= "age";
    public static final String KEY_BIRTHDATE= "birthdate";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER= "gender";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME= "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASS= "password";

    DBHelper2 DB2 = null;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db5";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "registration1";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME
            + "("
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "givenname TEXT NOT NULL, firstname TEXT NOT NULL, middlename TEXT NOT NULL,address1 TEXT NOT NULL, address2 TEXT NOT NULL, cityvillage TEXT NOT NULL,stateprovince TEXT NOT NULL, country TEXT NOT NULL,postalcode TEXT NOT NULL, age TEXT NOT NULL, birthdate TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL,password TEXT NOT NULL );";

    public DBHelper2(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        System.out.println("In constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db2) {

        try {

            db2.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_CREATE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db2, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Cursor rawQuery(String string, String[] strings) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void open() {

        getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public Cursor getDetails(String text) throws SQLException 
    {

        Cursor mCursor = db2.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                 KEY_ROWID, KEY_GNAME, KEY_FNAME, KEY_MNAME,KEY_ADDRESS1,KEY_ADDRESS2,KEY_CITYVILLAGE,KEY_STATEPROVINCE,
                 KEY_COUNTRY,KEY_POSTALCODE,KEY_AGE,KEY_BIRTHDATE,KEY_GENDER,KEY_USERNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "=" + text, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }
}
```

Manifestfile.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.LoginActivity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.Registration" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.TabBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.Tab1" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.Tab2" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.Tab3" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Person"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_person" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.History"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Medications"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_medications" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddMedRecords"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_med_records" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.OfficeVisit"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_office_visit" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddOfficeVisit"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_office_visit" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.OfficeInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_office_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddOfficeInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_office_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.OfficeInfoExtraDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_office_info_extra_details" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.AddPerson" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.RenamePerson"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rename_person" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Weight"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_weight" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.WeightInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_weight_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.BloodPressure"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blood_pressure" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddBloodPressureInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_blood_pressure_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.BloodSugarCharts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blood_sugar_charts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.BloodSugar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blood_sugar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddHistory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.LabAndTestResults"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lab_and_test_results" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddLabTestResult"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_lab_test_result" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.app.DataAnalysis" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Welcome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.SimpleListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_simple_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.WeightCharts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_weight_charts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.BMICharts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bmicharts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.BloodSugarChart2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blood_sugar_chart2" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.BloodPressureCharts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blood_pressure_charts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Appointment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_appointment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddBloodSugarInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_blood_sugar_info" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AddAppointment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_appointment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Registration1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_activity1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Registration2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am unable to find the error..Everytime its showing usernamepassword mismatch..Please help

Comment: Run the debugger and check if the username and password you use on register is the same with the ones that are saved in your database. This way, you'll know if it is a problem on registration or login.

Comment: Actually earlier I did the same thing...it was running..But suddenly I am getting this.I am unable to find my mistake.I am getting null pointer Exception

Comment: Post the log when the null pointer exception happens

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shared preferences to save and retrieve  data instead of using database.
It is more simple for storing such simple name value pairs like login data.

**To save data:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

**To retrieve data:**

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name=sharedpreferences.getString(Name, "")
```

Check these for more details..
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Actually earlier I did the same thing...it was running..But suddenly I am getting this.I am unable to find my mistake.I am getting null pointer Exception

Comment: not shared preference...The above code which i have posted

Comment: did you find the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check for cursor.moveToFirst() than cursor count. If it returns true than db record exists else not exists